# Authorize.net returns E00006 after migrating to Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, authorize.net

I migrated my website from laravel 4.2 to laravel 5.1. But after migration my payment gateway(authorize.net) has stopped working. I have used authorize.net SDK V1.8 for php. Here is the response from authorize.net -

```
AuthorizeNetCIM_Response Object
(
    [xml] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [resultCode] => Error
                    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [code] => E00006
                            [text] => The API user name is invalid or not present.
                        )

                )

        )

    [response] => ﻿ErrorE00006The API user name is invalid or not present.
    [xpath_xml] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [messages] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [resultCode] => Error
                    [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [code] => E00006
                            [text] => The API user name is invalid or not present.
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Can anyone explain me what does this error actually mean "**The API user name is invalid or not present.**" and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Are you still using the same `Encryption Key` and `cipher` in your `app.config`?

Comment: yes, same as it was ealier in laravel 4.2